# Why does `current()` expects its argument to be a reference?

Tags: php

Its signature (from the docs):
`mixed current ( array &$array )`

It does not move the internal pointer, does not modify the array, and it does work without errors or notices with values:

```
>>> current([1])
=> 1
>>> reset([1])
PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference
```

Is this an abstraction leak from the underlying C code, or is it really a justified choice?

Comment: Because it's related to internal array pointer after looping (`next`, `last`, ...). reset of static array do not have any sense

Comment: @FieryCat, But does it _need_ it to be a reference?

Comment: Even more... it HAS to be a reference :) Revalidate PHP specification

Comment: When you use `current()`, it will just give you the current value where the pointer is, so if you supply an array directly, it'll just give you the first element. `reset()` moves the internal pointer, and thus needs a reference. If you use an array directly in it, the pointer will be at the beginning anyways.

Comment: @FieryCat, then it should not work with values? But it works. Why the inconsistence?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, @Qirel, `reset` works according to its signature, correctly, the question is about `current`.